# Convert to Json before send data for Authentication in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, authentication, post

I'm doing a web app. Right nowI'm doing the authentication page. The server is done with Django. But the server expects a json. How can I convert and what I have to convert before send data? Thanks!

This is the Authentication service code:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('AuthService', function ($http, $window, $q, API_SERVER) {

var authenticate = function (email, pwd, endpoint) {
  var url = API_SERVER + endpoint;
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.post(url, 'email=' + email + '&pwd=' + pwd, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(
    function (response) {
      var token = response.data.token;
      var email = response.data.email;

      if (token && email) {
        $window.localStorage.token = token;
        $window.localStorage.email = email;
        deferred.resolve(true);
      } else {
        deferred.reject('Invalid data received from server');
      }
    },
    function (response) {
      deferred.reject(response.data.error);
    }
  );
  return deferred.promise;
};

var logout = function () {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var url = API_SERVER + 'logout/';

  $http.post(url).then(
    function () {
      $window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
      $window.localStorage.removeItem('email');
      deferred.resolve();
    },
    function (error) {
      deferred.reject(error.data.error);
    }
  );
  return deferred.promise;
};

return {
  register: function (email, pwd) {
    return authenticate(email, pwd, 'accountmanager/');
  },
  login: function (email, pwd) {
    return authenticate(email, pwd, 'login/');
  },
  logout: function () {
    return logout();
  }
};

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
var obj = {
    email:email,
    pwd:pwd
}
$http.post(url, obj).then()
```